# =PRODUCT(FILTER(D6:G6,D6:G6<>0)) how to use this formula use epplush library

Tags: model-view-controller, epplus

```
            worksheet.Cells[row, 8].Formula =$"PRODUCT(FILTER(D{row}:G{row},D{row}:G{row}<>0))";
                        if (worksheet.Cells[row,8].Formula!="")
                        {
                            worksheet.Cells[row, 8].Calculate();
                        }
```

filter formula use
above my code how to use this formula in this